Whenever i changing the widget i am facing the issue of delay in overall performance and user interface while using serial COM
I'm using this PyQt5 code on the Raspberry Pi 4.
When I run the code, I receive and plot analog values on the plot_widget via serial communication.
If I change the mode or widget, and then attach the respective widget using the stackedWidget method, I face issues with receiving and plotting the data on the plot_widget and delayed in overall response.
This is leading to hanging conditions and slow the overall performance like user interface, or an inability to get the analog value from the serial communication.
I analysed the RAM memory and found that it's only taking up to 40-50% on that occasion.
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 480)
        self.MainWindow = MainWindow
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 442, 800, 35))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 71))
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        # Create a QLabel to hold the background image
        self.background_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.background_label.setGeometry(0, 0, MainWindow.width(), MainWindow.height())
        self.background_label.lower()  # Ensure the label is behind all other widgets
        self.MainScreen_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.MainScreen_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 5, 786, 61))
        self.MainScreen_widget.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 107, 122); /* Semi-transparent background */\n"
"    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); /* Semi-transparent border */\n"
"    border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */\n"

"}\n"
"")
        self.MainScreen_widget.setObjectName("MainScreen_widget")
        self.modeSelect_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.MainScreen_widget)
        self.modeSelect_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(333, 10, 81, 23))
        self.modeSelect_Button.setObjectName("modeSelect_Button")
        self.widgetSelect_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.MainScreen_widget)
        self.widgetSelect_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(305, 30, 141, 27))
        self.widgetSelect_Button.setObjectName("widgetSelect_Button")

        # Create a stacked widget to hold screens
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 72, 800, 340))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")

        # Initialize the modes and widgets dictionary
        self.modes = {
            "mode 1": [
                ("widget 1", mode_1_widget_1),
                ("widget 2", mode_1_widget_2),
                ("widget 3", mode_1_widget_3),
                ("widget 4", mode_1_widget_4)
            ],
            "mode 2": [
                ("widget 1", mode_2_widget_1),
                ("widget 2", mode_2_widget_2),
                ("widget 3", mode_2_widget_3),
            ],
            "mode 3": [
                ("widget 1", mode_3_widget_1)
            ]
        }
        # # Initial settings
        self.mode_index = 0
        self.widget_index = 0
        self.current_widget = None

        # Load the initial widget
        self.loadWidget()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def changeWidget(self):
        """Change the widget within the current mode."""
        mode = list(self.modes.keys())[self.mode_index]
        self.last_selected[mode] = (self.last_selected[mode] + 1) % len(self.modes[mode])
        self.loadWidget()

    def changeMode(self):
        """Change the mode and update the widget."""
        self.mode_index = (self.mode_index + 1) % len(self.modes)
        self.loadWidget()
        
    def loadWidget(self):
        """Load the widget corresponding to the current mode and widget index."""
        mode = list(self.modes.keys())[self.mode_index]
        widget_index = self.last_selected[mode]

        widget_class = self.modes[mode][widget_index][1]

        if self.current_widget:
            self.stackedWidget.removeWidget(self.current_widget)

        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.current_widget)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.current_widget)

        # Update the text on the widget button
        self.widgetSelect_Button.setText(self.modes[mode][widget_index][0])

        # Update the text on the mode button
        self.modeSelect_Button.setText(mode)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.modeSelect_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
        self.widgetSelect_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

For example mode_1_widget_1 code and it's similar for the all mode_1, mode_2, mode_3 widgets:
class Ui_mode_1_Widget_1(object):
    def setupUi(self, mode_1_Widget_1):
        mode_1_Widget_1.setObjectName("mode_1_Widget_1")
        mode_1_Widget_1.resize(800, 340)
        mode_1_Widget_1.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;\n"
"")
        self.data_1_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mode_1_Widget_1)
        self.data_1_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 768, 200))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.data_1_widget.setFont(font)
        self.data_1_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")
        self.data_1_widget.setObjectName("data_1_widget")
        self.data_1_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(mode_1_Widget_1)
        self.data_1_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(4, 120, 23, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.data_1_Label.setFont(font)
        self.data_1_Label.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(50, 255, 14);\n"
        "background-color:none")
        self.data_1_Label.setText("")
        self.data_1_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.data_1_Label.setObjectName("data_1_Label")

        self.retranslateUi(mode_1_Widget_1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mode_1_Widget_1)

        # Create PlotWidgets for each channel
        self.plot_widgets = {
            "R1": PlotWidget(mode_1_Widget_1)
        }

        # Set geometry for each PlotWidget based on the provided positions
        for channel, plot_widget in self.plot_widgets.items():
            plot_widget.setBackground(None)
            # Additional features
            plot_widget.hideAxis('left')
            plot_widget.hideAxis('bottom')
            plot_widget.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)  # Disable zooming
            plot_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")
            if channel.startswith("R"):
                if channel == "R1":
                    plot_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 768, 200))
            else:
                # Handle other channel names if needed
                pass
            plot_widget.setObjectName(channel + "_widget")

    def retranslateUi(self, mode_1_Widget_1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mode_1_Widget_1.setWindowTitle(_translate("mode_1_Widget_1", "Form"))
        self.data_1_Label.setText(_translate("mode_1_Widget_1", "R1"))

class mode_1_Widget_1(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_mode_1_Widget_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Initialize analog data dictionary
        self.analog_data = {channel: [] for channel in self.plot_widgets.keys()}
        
        # Initialize serial communication
        self.serial_connected = False
        self.init_serial()

        # Start receiving analog data
        self.start_analog_reception()

    def init_serial(self):
        try:
            self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout=1)  # Adjust the port and baud rate accordingly
            time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the serial connection to initialize
            self.serial_connected = True
        except serial.SerialException:
            print("SerialException: Could not open serial port")
            self.serial_connected = False

    def start_analog_reception(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_analog_plot)
        self.timer.start(100)  # Update every 100 ms
        self.analog_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_analog_data)
        self.analog_thread.daemon = True
        self.analog_thread.start()

    def update_analog_plot(self):
        for channel, plot_widget in self.plot_widgets.items():
            if self.analog_data[channel]:
                num_points = len(self.analog_data[channel])
                x = np.linspace(0, num_points - 1, num_points)  # Adjust x array length
                analog_values = self.analog_data[channel][::-1]
                # Ensure the length of analog_values matches the length of x
                analog_values = analog_values[:len(x)]
                plot_widget.plot(x, analog_values, clear=True, pen=mkPen(color='g', width=1))  # Plot as a continuous line
            else:
                # If no data received, plot a single thin line
                plot_widget.plot([0], [0], clear=True, pen=mkPen(color='g', width=1))  # Plot a single thin line

    def receive_analog_data(self):
        while True:
            if not self.serial_connected:
                # If the serial connection is not established, append '0'
                for channel in self.analog_data.keys():
                    self.analog_data[channel].append(0)
                    if len(self.analog_data[channel]) > 3000:  # Keep only the latest 2000 data points
                        self.analog_data[channel].pop(0)
                time.sleep(1)  # Wait for a second before trying again
                self.init_serial()  # Try to reconnect the serial port
                continue
            try:
                line = self.ser.readline().strip()
                if line:
                    try:
                        analog_value = int(line.decode('utf-8'))
                        for channel in self.analog_data.keys():
                            self.analog_data[channel].append(analog_value)
                            if len(self.analog_data[channel]) > 3000:  # Keep only the latest 2000 data points
                                self.analog_data[channel].pop(0)
                    except UnicodeDecodeError:
                        # Handle UnicodeDecodeError gracefully
                        print("UnicodeDecodeError: Invalid byte received")
                else:
                    # If no value received, append "0" to all channels
                    for channel in self.analog_data.keys():
                        self.analog_data[channel].append(0)
                        if len(self.analog_data[channel]) > 3000:  # Keep only the latest 2000 data points
                            self.analog_data[channel].pop(0)
            except serial.SerialException:
                print("SerialException: Issue with the serial connection")
                self.serial_connected = False  # Mark serial connection as disconnected
            except ValueError:
                print("ValueError: Unable to convert data to integer")
                continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = mode_1_Widget_1()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

